# Angular Life cycle change event not fire in my code

Tags: angular

I have created one component for testing purposes to check the `ngOnChanges()` fire or not.
As I learn that the `ngOnChanges()` is the kick start event that fires after the `Constructor()` gets executed, but in my application it not working.

My TS Code

```
constructor() { 
    console.log("constructor");
  }
  ngOnChanges(){ console.log("ngOnChanges"); }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }
  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log("ngOnDestroy");
  }
  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log("ngDoCheck");
  }
  ngAfterContentInit(){ console.log("ngAfterContentInit"); }
  ngAfterContentChecked(){ console.log("ngAfterContentChecked"); }
  ngAfterViewInit(){ console.log("ngAfterViewInit"); }
  ngAfterViewChecked(){ console.log("ngAfterViewChecked"); }
```

HTML PAGE CODE

```
<h2>Test My Angular Life Cycle</h2>
<input type="buttton" value=""/>
```

Comment: You need to show the entire Component class and annotations. This is just a bunch of functions, we can't help with just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch only detections triggered by change from component outside.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pzsl81

Answer (score 2):

ngOnChanges will call before ngOnInit() only if the component has bound inputs and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change. if your component has no inputs or you use it without providing any inputs, the framework will not call ngOnChanges().

Answer (score 0):

Does your component implements life cycle interfaces?

I mean

```
export MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy..{
 ...
}
```

Comment: I m using   @Input() myName:string="";

Comment: You don't need to implement the Angular lifecycle interfaces, you just need to import them. It's considered good practice and will help you implement functions in the interfaces but is indistinguishable at runtime.

Comment: I doubt he's actually annotated the class as a `@Component`.